# How to deal with "Compiled without X-Windows - can not run viewer"?

Tags: xorg, compiling

(Sorry if I posted incorrectly here. But I think it is more related to Ubuntu)

I am running Gromacs 5.0.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

When I run `gmx view -f dppc-md.xtc -s dppc-md.tpr` I got the following:

`Compiled without X-Windows - can not run viewer`

I was suggested by Gromacs expert: "You'll need to install X11 headers and libraries (the package is called `xorg-dev`, off the top of my head), and use `cmake .. -DGMX_X11=on` before compiling & installing."

I have tried the below and they both worked, but `gmx view …` still did not work, with the same issue `Compiled without X-Windows - can not run viewer`

`sudo apt-get install xorg-dev`

`sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`

Can I ask how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you remove your Gromacs before you recompiled a new one?  From your source directory for Gromacs, you should be able to run `sudo make uninstall` to remove it.

Comment: @Terrance  Do you mean I should 1) remove my current Gromacs, 2) install xorg-dev as I have said in the post, 3) install the Gromacs again. So that I can use "gmx view ..." ?